Which files are inside of a bootable macOS USB created with macOS Terminal?
I need a list or a screenshot of them to replicate them because the bootable created in Windows Transmac just has a PKG file therefore not recognized as a bootable device.
I tried creating a blank file named boot.efi and it gets recognized as a bootable device, but it is the Windows 10 installed in the other ´´internal drive´´ that boots up. As I remember, there are more files.
I opened the DMG file in Transmac and saw the files. There is only the PKG file. This means Transmac only makes a copy of the files of in the DMG and does not make the USB bootable. So, I need to know which files are created with the Terminal that makes the USB bootable.
I don't have other way. I can’t get to Internet Recovery in any possible way. I don’t own a second mac. I can't create a macOS VM, because no VM app for Windows supports DMG as I have tried already. When trying to convert DMG to ISO, I get a broken file that can’t boot in any VM.

What practical problem are you looking to solve this way? Stating the problem will help people understand why you think your method will help, or may be able to suggest a better way. This is commonly known as an XY problem

Are you trying to create a bootable macOS installer disk? There's going to be hundreds of files on it. What Mac model do you have?

I want to create a bootable macOS installer but in windows every app just copy and past the .pkg file inside the DMG unlike terminal that writes more file including the one thah makes the use booteable so i think the only way is to replicate the missing files

From what you have described so far, the files you are looking for probably would be inside PKG file. As you have already determined, these files cannot be extracted using Transmac. Your request to list or screenshot cannot be fulfilled unless you identify which DMG file you are using. Can you also post which version of OS X/macOS you are trying to install?

@Marc Wilson need to install macOS El Capitan in my mac, i am using windows because internet recovery does not work so only option is look for a solution in the windows 10 it has

I believe you are not even close to understanding how to create an El Capitan bootable installer by using a Windows machine. The proper steps are given as the accepted answer to the question How can I use Windows to create an OS X El Capitan or macOS Sierra USB flash drive installer from the disk image (.dmg) file downloaded from Apple?.
